# enable/disable external sharing in SharePoint and Teams using Rest API?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

Can we enable/disable external sharing  in SharePoint and Teams using Rest API?
i am not getting any documentation related to this query.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, we cannot enable/disable external sharing through Rest API

We have to go to the admin center(needs to have admin permissions) to change external sharing settings.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off